# gVIM breaks symlinks on windows?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to keep my gVIM config in centralized place. For this, i have done

```
mklink c:\users\me\.vimrc c:\users\me\configs\_vimrc
```

That works fine until i change $MYVIMRC inside VIM. This instantly breaks symlink (c:\users\me.vimrc stop being a symlink and became ordinary file). Is it any way to fix this trange behavior?
OS is Windows Vista with latest updates. gVIM is 7.2 from official site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim is *supposed* to handle this correctly by default. (:help backupcopy)

By default, on non-unix platforms, backupcopy is set to "auto". It will normally rename the file and write a new changed file when you save, but should modify the original file if the original file is a link or has a resource fork, etc.

Several possibilities:

1. Your version of vim does not recognize the file is a symlink.
2. You've set backupcopy or a related variable (breaksymlink?) to override default behavior.

I'd be surprised if it's 1, since you're dealing with a recent version of vim. Does this happen if you have an empty .vimrc?

Comment: You are right, setting 'set backupcopy=yes' fixes problem on Vista+. Thanks!

Comment: Was backupcopy set to no before? auto is probably a better setting than yes, assuming it works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mklink /J c:\users\me c:\users\me\configs
```

This will create a hardlink directory junction between `c:\users\me`  and `c:\users\me\configs` that vista will respect when you rewrite you vimrc.

Comment: Have you tried this? The equivalent, in linux at least, would *not* work, because vim writes out a new file and copies it over when you save.

Comment: Oh, it's a directory link and not a file link, nevermind my previous comment.

Comment: Linking entire HOME folder is kind of... painful :)

Comment: Consider it to be the... Spleen of Hell ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The user *xaizek*  suggested an **workaround** in the comments of a related question I asked: [Symlink to .vimrc on windows makes file readonly upon write. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/468579/symlink-to-vimrc-on-windows-makes-file-readonly-upon-write-why#comment551604_468579). I've adopted his solution, but made the `$MYVIMRC`  assignment conditional because I use both Windows and OSX systems:

So, in my Windows `~/.vimrc` file I have:

```
source /path/to/shared/vimrc
```

Then, in the shared `.vimrc` file I have:

```
if has("win32")
    let $MYVIMRC='~/path/to/shared/.vimrc'
endif
```