# Symlink to .vimrc on windows makes file readonly upon write. Why?

Tags: windows, vim, symbolic-link, vimrc

I've put my `.vimrc` file in a central location (dropbox folder, also a hg repository).

Under Windows 7, I've symlinked to it from my home folder (strangely enough I had to do it as an administrator, otherwise I got 'no permission'):

```
C:\users\Me>mklink .vimrc C:\users\me\dropbox\dotfiles\.vimrc
```

After fixing an overwrite issue by using `set backupcopy=yes` (found here: [gVIM breaks symlinks on windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/52891/gvim-breaks-symlinks-on-windows)), I have another issue. 
When I save the modified file, the real `.vimrc` (in my `dropbox/dotfiles` folder) gets a read-only flag as soon as I save it (using `:w`).

Why is this?
How can I prevent this?

Comment: I can propose another way of solving symlink issue, which I use on Windows XP machines. Create `_vimrc` with one line `source /path/to/real/vimrc` and update `$MYVIMRC` variable in your real `vimrc` file, e.g. `let $MYVIMRC='/path/to/real/vimrc'`. Maybe this will solve your current issue.

Comment: @xaizek: I've adopted your solution. No more annoying windows symlink stuff...

Comment: OK, just did it. I wasn't sure whether it's the right thing to do, since my comment doesn't really answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can propose another way of solving symlink issue, which I use on Windows XP machines or on Windows 7 without administrative rights.

Create `_vimrc` file with one line

```
source /path/to/real/vimrc
```

and update `$MYVIMRC` variable in your real `vimrc` file, e.g.

```
let $MYVIMRC='/path/to/real/vimrc'
```

Changing value of `$MYVIMRC` is useful for referring to correct `vimrc` file (for example in autocommands that reread it) on different systems.